# Learning defaultdict(list), Trying to make arrays of objects that have object arrays under them

Tags: python-2.7, data-structures

My python program before is me trying to make an array of many arrays under the top like so

Some Object1
    Array of objects under some object 1
Some Object2
    Array of objects under this one as well.

This is the full python program I have.  It seems right looking at it but the second list thinks there is only one item in it, like the append of the list doesnt append the full list.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
import os
import sys
import json
from pprint import pprint
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import numbers
import decimal
import re

import json
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime
import os
from collections import defaultdict

class SomeClass:
    i = 1
    name = "myname"
    pointX = 232.12
    pointY = 321.2

x=SomeClass()
x.name='first parent'
x.pointX = - 500

y=SomeClass()
y.name='Second Parent'
y.pointX = -1000
t=SomeClass()
t.name = 'first child of first set'
t.pointX = -113
t.pointY = -23
u=SomeClass()
u.name = "Another Name"
v=SomeClass()
v.name ="Last Name"

q = SomeClass()
q.name ='another child 2'
q.pointX = -250
q.pointY = -250

w = SomeClass()
w.name = 'Child 2'
w.pointX = 750
w.pointY = 750
def main():

    parents=[x, y]
    children1 = [ t,  u,  v]
    children2 = [q  , w]
    d = defaultdict(list)

    somevar =0
    for p in parents:
        if somevar==0:
            d[p].append(children1)
        else:
            d[p].append(children2)
        somevar+=1
    print d
    for e in d:
        print "Pname: " + str(e.name) + " " + str(e.pointX) + " " + str(e.pointY) + " numc: " + str(len(d[e])) #should be len of children1 and len of children2.  it is 1 both times
        counter=0
        for z in d[e]:
            print "\t\t" + z[counter].name + " " + str(z[counter].pointX) + " " + str(z[counter].pointY)
            counter+=1 #no idea how to really iterate through this, doing a z.name gave an error as it seemed like it was an array of itself

main()  #kick it all off
```

The output:

```
Pname: first parent -500 321.2 numc: 1
        first child of first set -113 -23
Pname: Second Parent -1000 321.2 numc: 1
        another child 2 -250 -250
```

To me it should be showing more children, 3 for the first parent and 2 for the second?

Comment: What would happen if `d[p].append(children#)` would become `d[p].extend(children#)`?

Comment: It works :) lol ty!